# Throwing Error Running slf4j-api through Maven

Tags: java, maven

#### Entry in my porm.xml for slf4j

```
enter code here
   <dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.7</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

#### score code:

```
package test.test1;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
/**
 * Hello world!
 *
*/
public class App 
{
  public static void main( String[] args )
  {
    //System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("App.class");
logger.info("Test");

  }
}
```

#### Compiling is successful through Maven, but during Running Exception is thrown.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFacto
ry at test.test1.App.main(App.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
```

Should set the classpath manually for slf4j jar file??

Comment: How do you set the application classpath when launching the app? Make sure that you include the `slf4j` library as well as your other dependencies

Comment: This is the same question I am asking, as far dependencies is consider I think its rite. Exception "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:" in eclipse is solved by adding .jar to classpath. So how it is managed through Maven.

Answer (score 0):

Maven picks up the dependencies you defined in the `pom.xml` from your local repository so everything compiles fine. However when you launch the application from a script or commandline you need to specify where the necessary classes are found, through the [classpath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html).

For eclipse, there's the [m2e](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/) & [m2e-wtp](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e-wtp/) plugins which integrate maven with your IDE so you don't need to add the jars manually one by one. Instead you'll have a sort of "virtual maven library" which contains references to all your dependencies, like in the image below:
[image: maven library]